# How rely the orientation of an object facing the camera to the side it's looked at?

Tags: constraints, drivers

**Use case / goal**

See the images below.
The green plane is attached to a target, the grey sphere, and is facing the camera, but its orientation change depending on witch side of the target the camera is looking at. The plane and target orientations are indicated by colored arrows.

The illustration below uses keyframes to switch the green plane orientation, the goal would be to completely automatize this reaction.
It would be implemented on top of a complex setup, and need to give correct result in any possible orientation context.

[image: a plane facing camera switch its orientation depending on witch side it's looked at]
[image: a plane facing camera switch its orientation depending on witch side it's looked at]

**Tried setup**

Whether the first part of the job (facing the camera) have been done, the problem is to define the right moment to switch from a side to another :

1. By using a constraint on the green plan, for example a Locked Track, the constraint axis need then to be switched (from "Z" to "-Z" for example) according to which side of the object is looked at.
2. By defining all the orientation of the green plane in a driver, by processing the two objects rotation values, the code need to switch its result according to which side of the object is looked at.

This right moment may be defined by an angular difference between the camera and the target. Given `cam` the value of the Z Rotation transform channel of the camera, and `target` the value of the Z Rotation transform channel of the target (both in World Space and in `[-pi, pi]`), a naive approach may define this moment by : `cam < target`. Thus, due to the angular system (0 to pi in a side, 0 to -pi in another) this approach do not work when the target may be oriented in any side, and the camera may cross the "pi zone".

**Synthesized problem**

How to define which side of the target the camera is looking at, in any possible orientation of the target and the camera ? Which formula would give the correct moment where the side is crossed, in any orientation context ?

Or what any other setup may reach the illustrated goal ?

Comment: Wouldn't transforming the camera into object space of the target and determining which halfspace the camera is on work? That would basically boil down to `if camloc.axisofchoice < 0` kind of thing?

Comment: I guess this would be a/the solution, but i have failed to implement it until now. Someone more comfortable with mathematics  may give a try.